# {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.net.UnknownHostException: proxy

Tags: java, soap, proxy, axis, unknown-host

**Need Your Immediate answer. thanks in advance**

i am getting this error when consume soap service by using WSDL URL.
    if i run that consumed services in main method.it gave correct result.but when i call that same service in rest Services.it gave following error
 Consuming services:SOAP services
 Languange:JAVA
 Technologies using: Spring,hibernate,rest services

**CODE:**
    package com.incture.rest;

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import oneapp.incture.workbox.consumer.wsdl.UMEManagementEngineConsumer;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/test",produces="application/json")
public class TestRest {

    UMEManagementEngineConsumer umeConsumer;

    @RequestMapping(value="/ume",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<String> getUsersAssignedInGroup(@RequestParam(name="userGroup",required=false)String userGroup) {

        umeConsumer=new UMEManagementEngineConsumer();

        List<String> list=umeConsumer.getUsersAssignedInGroup(userGroup);
        for(String s:list){
            System.err.println(s);
        }       
        return list;
    }
}
**CODE:**
package oneapp.incture.workbox.consumer.wsdl;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException;

import org.apache.axis.client.Stub;

import com.incture.pmc.poadapter.services.UMEUserManagementFacade;
import com.incture.pmc.poadapter.services.UMEUserManagementFacadeBindingStub;
import com.incture.pmc.poadapter.services.UMEUserManagementFacadeServiceLocator;

public class UMEManagementEngineConsumer {

    private UMEUserManagementFacade getFacadePort() {
        try {
            return new UMEUserManagementFacadeServiceLocator().getUMEUserManagementFacadePort();
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private UMEUserManagementFacade setStubProperties(UMEUserManagementFacade port) {
        UMEUserManagementFacadeBindingStub stub = (UMEUserManagementFacadeBindingStub) port;
        stub._setProperty(Stub.USERNAME_PROPERTY, PMCConstant.WBuserId);
        stub._setProperty(Stub.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, PMCConstant.WBpassword);
        return port;
    }

    public List<String> getUsersAssignedInGroup(String userGroup) {
        UMEUserManagementFacade port = setStubProperties(getFacadePort());
        List<String> usersGroup = null;
        try {
            String[] users = port.getUsersAssignedInGroup(userGroup);
            if(!ServicesUtil.isEmpty(users)){
                usersGroup = new ArrayList<String>();
                usersGroup = Arrays.asList(users);
            }
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return usersGroup;
    }

}




   10:47:14.715 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR org.apache.axis.AxisFault - AxisFault
     faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
     faultSubcode: 
     faultString: java.net.UnknownHostException: proxy
     faultActor: 
     faultNode: 
     faultDetail: 
        {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.net.UnknownHostException: proxy
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.axis.components.net.DefaultSocketFactory.create(DefaultSocketFactory.java:153)
        at org.apache.axis.components.net.DefaultSocketFactory.create(DefaultSocketFactory.java:125)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:191)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:404)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)
        at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
        at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
        at com.incture.pmc.poadapter.services.UMEUserManagementFacadeBindingStub.getUsersAssignedInGroup(UMEUserManagementFacadeBindingStub.java:390)
        at oneapp.incture.workbox.consumer.wsdl.UMEManagementEngineConsumer.getUsersAssignedInGroup(UMEManagementEngineConsumer.java:38)
        at com.incture.rest.TestRest.getUsersAssignedInGroup(TestRest.java:23)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:859)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
        at com.sap.cloud.runtime.impl.bridge.security.AbstractAuthenticator.invoke(AbstractAuthenticator.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
        at com.sap.cloud.runtime.kotee.jta.cleaner.LeakedTransactionsReportValve.invoke(LeakedTransactionsReportValve.java:155)
        at com.sap.core.tenant.valve.TenantValidationValve.invokeNextValve(TenantValidationValve.java:182)
        at com.sap.core.tenant.valve.TenantValidationValve.invoke(TenantValidationValve.java:97)
        at com.sap.js.statistics.tomcat.valve.RequestTracingValve.callNextValve(RequestTracingValve.java:101)
        at com.sap.js.statistics.tomcat.valve.RequestTracingValve.invoke(RequestTracingValve.java:57)
        at com.sap.core.js.monitoring.tomcat.valve.RequestTracingValve.invoke(RequestTracingValve.java:27)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

        {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:INCTN241

    10:47:14.723 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable - java.net.UnknownHostException: proxy
    10:47:14.725 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)
    10:47:14.725 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:154)
    10:47:14.726 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    10:47:14.726 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    10:47:14.727 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    10:47:14.728 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
    10:47:14.728 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    10:47:14.729 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    10:47:14.729 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    10:47:14.730 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    10:47:14.730 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    10:47:14.730 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at com.incture.pmc.poadapter.services.UMEUserManagementFacadeBindingStub.getUsersAssignedInGroup(UMEUserManagementFacadeBindingStub.java:390)
    10:47:14.731 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at oneapp.incture.workbox.consumer.wsdl.UMEManagementEngineConsumer.getUsersAssignedInGroup(UMEManagementEngineConsumer.java:38)
    10:47:14.731 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at com.incture.rest.TestRest.getUsersAssignedInGroup(TestRest.java:23)
    10:47:14.732 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    10:47:14.732 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    10:47:14.732 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    10:47:14.733 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    10:47:14.734 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    10:47:14.734 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    10:47:14.734 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    10:47:14.735 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817)
    10:47:14.736 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731)
    10:47:14.736 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    10:47:14.736 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    10:47:14.737 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    10:47:14.737 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
    10:47:14.737 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:859)
    10:47:14.737 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    10:47:14.738 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    10:47:14.738 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    10:47:14.739 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    10:47:14.739 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    10:47:14.739 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    10:47:14.739 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    10:47:14.740 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    10:47:14.740 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    10:47:14.741 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    10:47:14.741 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    10:47:14.741 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    10:47:14.741 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at com.sap.cloud.runtime.impl.bridge.security.AbstractAuthenticator.invoke(AbstractAuthenticator.java:206)
    10:47:14.742 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    10:47:14.742 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
    10:47:14.743 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    10:47:14.743 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at com.sap.cloud.runtime.kotee.jta.cleaner.LeakedTransactionsReportValve.invoke(LeakedTransactionsReportValve.java:155)
    10:47:14.743 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at com.sap.core.tenant.valve.TenantValidationValve.invokeNextValve(TenantValidationValve.java:182)
    10:47:14.743 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at com.sap.core.tenant.valve.TenantValidationValve.invoke(TenantValidationValve.java:97)
    10:47:14.743 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at com.sap.js.statistics.tomcat.valve.RequestTracingValve.callNextValve(RequestTracingValve.java:101)
    10:47:14.744 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at com.sap.js.statistics.tomcat.valve.RequestTracingValve.invoke(RequestTracingValve.java:57)
    10:47:14.744 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at com.sap.core.js.monitoring.tomcat.valve.RequestTracingValve.invoke(RequestTracingValve.java:27)
    10:47:14.744 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    10:47:14.744 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    10:47:14.745 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    10:47:14.745 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    10:47:14.745 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    10:47:14.746 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    10:47:14.746 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    10:47:14.747 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    10:47:14.747 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    10:47:14.747 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    10:47:14.748 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    10:47:14.748 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    10:47:14.749 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable - Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: proxy
    10:47:14.749 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    10:47:14.749 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    10:47:14.750 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    10:47:14.750 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    10:47:14.750 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    10:47:14.750 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    10:47:14.750 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    10:47:14.750 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    10:47:14.750 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.axis.components.net.DefaultSocketFactory.create(DefaultSocketFactory.java:153)
    10:47:14.751 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.axis.components.net.DefaultSocketFactory.create(DefaultSocketFactory.java:125)
    10:47:14.751 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:191)
    10:47:14.751 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:404)
    10:47:14.751 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)
    10:47:14.751 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     ... 60 more
```

Comment: Add code which causes this issue

Comment: hello,Anuraag Baishya thanks for responding.can you check now